# Checking for white space in fields of Excel spreadsheets?

Tags: excel

I just wanted to ask this for future reference, is there a good reliable way to check for white space in excel spreadsheets and such you receive from others?

Three or four times now I've had problems performing joins because of this, I just wanted to know if there is a good consistent way to check for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TRIM in excel,

Removes all spaces from text except for single spaces between words. Use TRIM on text that you have received from another application that may have irregular spacing.

Syntax

TRIM(text)  You only really need it on the join field.